Duplicate key error when doing INSERT with JPA native query
I am trying to run a JPA native query which will INSERT data in a postgres database.
However I am getting the following error :
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "myentity_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id)=(0) already exists.

The entity Code looks like this :
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name="my_entity")
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String value;
}

Repository code looks like this :
@Repository
public class MyEntityRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    public void save(MyEntity me) {
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO my_entity (id, value) VALUES (?, ?)");
        query.setParameter(1, me.getId());
        query.setParameter(2, me.getValue());
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
}

Anyone got any ideas?
I have tried changing the generated value strategy to IDENTITY but no joy.

Detail: Key (id)=(0) already exists. - possible, your me.getId() always return 0. Then, if you try use generated identity, do not include column id to insert statement: INSERT INTO my_entity (value) VALUES (?)

With JPA you typically use repositories to perform database operations. In your case you would use myEntityRepository.save(me) and do not provide and id. It will be generated for you. You are asking the DB provider to generate the id when specifying GenerationType.AUTO and GenerationType.IDENTITY yet you are manually providing and id. Define a repository like such:
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JPARepository(MyEntity, Long, ) {}
and imply call
myEntityRepository.save(me);
without providing an id.
Also, change your id type from long to Long two unmanaged entities would have the same id which is not what you want.
If you don't want to use repositories remove the id generation type to and make sure you are passing in unique ids.

Thanks for the answer but it needs to use a native query.

If you have to use a native query remove the @GeneratedValue and you need to make sure the id you are using is unique. You can verify uniqueness with a query before saving the entity.
